# duda con simbolos "?" y " _/ "en las url

Tags: archivo, url, hosting, querystring

[image]

en el primer archivo logo17.html?hl=es

y en la segunda _/

mi ignorancia me pide a gritos saber el por que ese archivo y esa carpeta tienen esos símbolos y que significan , para que se usan .
cuando trato de guardar un archivo similar en un hosting no he podido o no se muestran igual

Answer (score 1):

Con respecto a tu primer pregunta:

en la primer ruta logo17.html?hl=es

tu ruta es logo17.html  con el signo ? indicas que agregaras un parametro hl el valor
del parametro hl= es.

entonces envias una llamada hacia el servidor mediante query string
ventajas:

1. facil uso

desventajas:

Tienen un tamaño máximo.   -Los parametros quedan visibles, hay que tener cuidado con la información que se maneja.

```
-Los parametros quedan accesibles a ser modificados por el usuario facilmente.

-Tiene limitaciones con respecto a algunos caracteres especiales.
```

saludos